# Facebook Login not working on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm having an issue to make the Facebook iOS login work on iOS 11.

The login button doesn't work and the error `Unknown error building URL` is raised.

After investigation, the URL builder tries to build with the following query :

> ?auth_type=rerequest&client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&default_audience=friends&display=touch&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A234116.8327615%7D&fbapp_pres=1&**logging_token=<null>**&redirect_uri=fbXXXXXXXXXXX%3A%2F%2Fauthorize%2F&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&return_scopes=true&scope=email&sdk=ios&sdk_version=4.31.0&state=%7B%22challenge%22%3A%22BES6pJasUuEwLGbNptpQcWpkmIQ%253D%22%2C%220_auth_logger_id%22%3A%226E11D9DA-A14C-471A-9601-71B8FE6B2736%22%2C%22com.facebook.sdk_client_state%22%3Atrue%2C%223_method%22%3A%22sfvc_auth%22%7D

(App ID is obfuscated).

The issue I found is that the URL building step in FBSDKInternalUtility:417 fails because of **logging_token=<null>**, if I manually change the code of the pod file to ignore this query parameter it goes just fine.

Does one have an idea why such an error appears, and furthermore what is this logging_token for (no doc anywhere for it)? My plist is fine, implementation is fine too.

Using last FBSDKLoginKit (4.31)